Add certificate or license to LinkedIn does not work with link on mobile
In our javascript application, we provide the recipients of our clients with the ability to attach their certifications to their LinkedIn profiles.
To achieve this, we use the LinkedIn API link with the necessary parameters.
Now, we have encountered a problem where the modal no longer appears when the user is on a mobile device.
Here are the different cases:
Mobile (with deep link): Opening the application will not show the modal.
Mobile (with URL in default browser): The modal will not show up.
We have only noticed this issue on Android smartphones so far.
We changed the handling in our application from window.open to creating, clicking, and removing an anchor element.
In both methods, it still does not work.
Our link is created according to the LinkedIn documentation: https://addtoprofile.linkedin.com/
Additional a side-question.
Is it possible to use the mobile app to auth an application or is it neccessary to use the browser?
Try different methodes to open app and web app.
Reached out to LinkedIn-support.

I assume that you have already implemented a fallback?

Nope. I dont. I almoste waiting for help :(
